# Do I have to buy a game again in order to redownload it?

Tags: xbox-one

I am running out of storage, I usually have bought a lot of my games on disk but if I buy a game on the store then delete it, and want to redownload it do I have to buy it again

Answer (score 17):

No, after you buy a game it is associated with your Xbox Live account and you can download it as many times as you'd like for no additional charge. This also includes apps, most subscriptions and DLC, and Any Backwards compatible game (From the Xbox 360, of course!)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but only if you are downloading again onto the same xbox model you originally downloaded to. Be careful - I just bought an xbox one x. Came to download Skyrim again only to be told I had to buy the enhanced version at $50.00. This con trick applied to other titles. A lot of 360 games not available on xbox one. FX Pin Ball - I just lost 25 tables as they are not compatible. Be Warned!!

Comment: Shouldn't it be "No, but only..."? This is about having to re-buy games on a different console: that's not an answer to the question.